# How to switch k8s object from one namespace to another one?

Tags: kubernetes

Let's suppose I've got following manifests like deployment, services and ingress. All it works fine in default namespace. Although I want to throw resources to another namespace created with manifest.yaml. I thought if I wrote **kubectl appy -f $DIR** it would work as expected: objects would be moved to another namespace. But nothing changed.

To sum up, how can force moving objects to another namespace?

Comment: Using the command `kubectl apply -f $DIR --namespace <your-namespace>`, you can deploy your manifests in the namespace of your choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either edit all the deployment yamls to add `namespace` or you can run `kubectl apply -f $DIR -n namespacename`. This command will deploy all the yamls to namespace `namespacename`

Edit:

The thing to understand here is you can not move resources from one namespace to another namespace just by changing the namespace in the yaml. If you do that It will just create another copy of the same resource in another namespace. Delete from previous namespace and recreate in new namespace is the right approach.

Comment: I explicitly specified namespace in other yamls and then tried kubectl apply -f $DIR but it did not force to change namespace

Comment: So you already applied the yamls before in another namespace? Then you need to first run kubectl delete -f $DIR and then edit the yamls to change the namespace and then run kubectl apply -f $DIR

Comment: Yes, I've already applied before creating a new namespace. Do I understand correctly that I can't use the namespace without deleting and then applying?

Comment: The thing to understand here is you can not move resources from one namespace to another namespace just by changing the namespace in the yaml. If you do that It will just create another copy of the same resource in another namespace. Delete and recreate is the approach